# Electron-React error: I keep getting undefined error while reading 'ipcRenderer'

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to create a desktop application using Electron and React.

I set the basic settings using electron-react-boilerplate.

https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

However, I continued to receive  `can't resolve fs module not found` error.

To solve this error, I performed the method suggested in document https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/docs/native-modules/#native-modules-in-electron-react-boilerplate. (activate node integration)

Then I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ipcRenderer')`. but strangely, an error warning window appears, but the app runs normally.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

currently, i comment all of following code in `src/renderer/index.tsx`

```
// calling IPC exposed from preload script
window.electron.ipcRenderer.once('ipc-example', (arg) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(arg);
});
window.electron.ipcRenderer.myPing();
```